# Suitable I2C Alternative for Audio Applications

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, audio

I've been looking at using a [MCP4725](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MCP4725) 12-bit DAC connected to a [TPA2016](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa2016d2.pdf?ts=1637010943767&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) audio amplifier to drive a small 0.5W loudspeaker from a ATtiny85 on an existing circuit I have. I've quickly realised that the MCP4725 isn't exactly up to scratch for what I need and the I2C is a bit limited for audio capability.

I'd really like to find a device, preferably I2C that has EEPROM capability where I can store up-to five "tones" of audio and then send small commands on the I2C bus to play these songs when required. I'd prefer to use I2C as I have two existing circuits and one only has I2C capabilities so if I could make a circuit that can be used with both devices that would save me a lot of time.

Is there something out there that can do this? Is there some form of I2C to I2S converter or something similar that I could use so that I don't have to upgrade my ATtiny? Would it be better to just upgrade both ATTiny devices and use the SPI lines and find an IO expander or multiplexer for the device?

Comment: How long would these tones or songs be? Most likely such a chip does not exist. How much do you want to avoid switching to a MCU with enough memory and built-in DAC, as it is most likely cheaper?

Comment: The tones would be no more than a single word or phrase. Probably no more than two seconds of audio in total. It would be much better to avoid switching out the MCU purely because I can get ATTinys at the minute (whereas a lot of other parts are much more expensive due to component shortages).

Comment: So now instead of tones or music, it's sampled audio? At what sampling rate? How many bits per sample? How much you have storage space to spend?

Comment: It could be tones, music or sampled audio. The quality of the audio almost depends entirely on whether there's a solution to my problem. If I have to sample at a lower rate or reduce the size of my audio to have a "moderate" but not brilliant audio quality, I'll accept that. 8kHz would be the absolute minimum for obvious reasons but if there's a different way of doing it that I'm missing I'd be grateful for the help.

Comment: EEPROM? 1 second of [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) 8kHz/mono/16-bit (passable) = 16kB.  Can get good quality/small by using a codec (AAC, MP3, etc) but then decoding complexity increases.  For dedicated audio bus, see [I2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I²S).

Comment: Can you clarify why "the MCP4725 isn't exactly up to scratch for what I need and the I2C is a bit limited for audio capability."? We could guess, but it would be better if you spelled out the problems you've identified and what solutions you have considered.